# Symmetric matrix, a>0 on diagonal and b<0 off diagonal, positive definite?

Tags: matrices, positive-semidefinite

this came up in a specific example that I'm working on, but I'm wondering under what conditions it's true in general.

Consider an nxn matrix, all of whose diagonal entries are a>0 and all of whose non-diagonal entries are b<0. Is the matrix positive (semi)definite?

In the specific example I'm interested in, n=10000, a=17.552 and b=-0.00175538. But I'm interested in the question in general too.

Thanks

Edit: The general 2x2 case is easy to work out by hand. There, the matrix is positive definite (respectively semidefinite) if and only if a+b>0 (respectively >= 0). But what about in general?

Answer (score 1):

Not true. Just take $1$ along the diagonal and $-10$ off diagonal in a $2 \times 2$ matrix.

Comment: The off diagonal elements have to be small in absolute value compared to the  diagonal elements to get non-negtive definiteness.

Answer (score 1):

In general (see answer by Kavi Rama Murthy), this is not true, but if the diagonal values are large, and off diagonals are small, then the [Gershgorin circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) might give you enough info to prove that the matrix has only positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Yes, that answers it.

Now I'm even more curious... Suppose a=(n-1)|b|. Are the eigenvalues going to be exactly 0 (multiplicity 1) and n|b| (multiplicity n-1)? That's how it looks in the examples I've put into the computer.

Comment: The vector $v$ with constant coefficients equal to $1$ is eigen. For  $a=-(n-1)b$, it corresponds to the eigenvalue $0$. As your matrix is symetric, it is diagonalisable on a orthonormal basis. Set $V=v^{\perp}$,  Check that $OMO^{-1}=M$ for every $O\in O(n)$ that let $v$ (thus $V$) stable. This implies that $M$ as a single eigenvalue on $V$, which thus has multiplicty $n-1$. Another way to do it is to verify that if $w\in V$ is eigen, then every permutation of its component is also eigen. A third way is to write your matrix as $cI-dE$ where $E$ is full 1, then use characteristic polynomial