# $n \times n$ matrix, $n-$1 on diagonal, $-1$ off diagonal, find eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

just wanted to pose a follow-up to the previous question I asked at [Symmetric matrix, $a>0$ on diagonal and $b<0$ off diagonal, positive definite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307191/symmetric-matrix-a0-on-diagonal-and-b0-off-diagonal-positive-definite):

Suppose we have an $n \times n$ matrix whose diagonal entries are $n-1$ and whose non-diagonal entries are $-1$. Show that the eigenvalues are 0 (multiplicity $1$) and $n$ (multiplicity $n-1$).

I got the following comment:

The vector $v$ with constant coefficients equal to $1$ is eigen. It corresponds to the eigenvalue $0$. As your matrix is symmetric, it is diagonalizable on an orthonormal basis. Set $V=v^\perp$. Check that $OMO^{-1}=M$ for every $O\in O(n)$ that let $v$ (thus $V$) stable. This implies $M$ as a single eigenvalue on $V$, which thus has multiplicity $n-1$. Another way to do it is to verify that if $w\in V$ is eigen, then every permutation of its components is also eigen. A third way is to write your matrix as $cI-dE$ where $E$ is full $1$, then use the characteristic polynomial.

Sorry, but I don't understand this answer. I got that $(1,1,...1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $0$. The orthogonal complement to this will be $\{(x_1,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n:x_1+...+x_n=0\}$. But from here it gets confusing.

- What is $M$? How would $OMO^{-1}=M$ for every $O\in O(n)$ (I assume that is the group of orthogonal matrices) imply that there is only one other eigenvalue?
- I assume he meant any permutation of the components of an eigenvector is also an eigenvector $\mathit{\text{with the same eigenvalue}}$. That's easy to show. But it still leaves the question of finding an eigenvector such that the subspace generated by its set of permutations of components has dimension $n-1$. How do I do that?
- In this case, that means $(n-1)I-E$. But to find the characteristic polynomial from here... Brute force?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a link to the previous question you asked. Thanks.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307191/symmetric-matrix-a0-on-diagonal-and-b0-off-diagonal-positive-definite/3307200

Comment: Thanks for giving the link. I forgot to mention to update your answer with that link. However, for this case, I've done that for you.

Answer (score 1):

What the question promises you is that there is an $n-1$ dimensional space with  all the vectors in it eigenvectors.  That is clearly the space perpendicular to $(1,1,1,\ldots 1)$.  A handy vector in that space is $(1-n,1,1,1,\ldots 1)$.  Can you prove that is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n$?  Now the symmetry of the problem says you can rotate the entries of the vector to put the $1-n$ in any location and it will still be an eigenvector.  You should be able to prove these vectors span the space of interest.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Showing that $(1-n,1,...1)$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $n$ was just 2 lines of calculation. To show that the subspace spanned by putting the 1-n is all possible locations is the space of interest... It's clearly a subspace. To show that it's the whole space, it's enough to show that adding one more vector spans all of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A good choice for that extra vector is $(0,1,1,...1)$. I can show inductively that $(1,0,...0), (0,1,0,...0), etc.$ are all in the expanded subspace.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

not sure what you are after, but call your symmetric matrix $M$ for $n=5,$ here is a matrix $P$ with the columns all being eigenvectors and all perpendicular to each other. You can make my matrix orthogonal by dividing each column by its length, which is a square root,.,, Note that $P^T MP$ is diagonal, although the diagonal entries may not be the exact eigenvalues unless you normalize the columns of $P$

$$    
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrrr}
  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  1  &  -1  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  2  &  -1  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  3  &  -1    \\
  1  &  0  &  0  &  0  &  4    \\
  \end{array}
\right).
$$